# Use Mongoose to find parent documents that match a query on a grand-child or great-grand-child document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-populate

I have a document structure, using object references for children, etc, similar to this:

```
REQUEST DOCUMENT
{
    "request" : "some request",
    "user" : ObjectId("1234") //reference to mongoose schema: USER
}

USER DOCUMENT - STANDARD USER
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("1234"),
    "name: "Bob Smith",
    "email": "bobSmith@acme.com",
    "manager": ObjectId("5678") //reference to mongoose schema: USER
}

USER DOCUMENT - MANAGER   
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5678"),
    "name: "John Doe",
    "email": "johnDoe@acme.com",
    "manager": ObjectId("9101112") //reference to mongoose schema: USER
}
```

If all the references were populated, it would look like this:

```
{
    "request" : "some request",
    "user" : { //reference to mongoose schema: USER
        "_id" : ObjectId("1234"),
        "name: "Bob Smith",
        "email": "bobSmith@acme.com",
        "manager": { //reference to mongoose schema: USER
            "_id" : ObjectId("5678"),
            "name: "John Doe",
            "email": "johnDoe@acme.com",
            "manager": ObjectId("9101112") 
        }
    } 
}
```

My goal is to log in as bob smith's manager (John Doe) and get a return of all requests of who's user, I am manager for so that I may approve them.

I can't seem to find a way to do this as a single query with mongoose.

I have tried this, and a few other variations, but I think i just misunderstanding $elemMatch, populate({ match }, and find().

Here is what does NOT work:

```
Request.find({ 'user.manager.email': 'johnDoe@acme.com' })
    .populate({
        path: 'user',
        populate: {
            path: 'manager'
        }
    }).exec(etc...)
```

This returns an empty array.

I have also tried:

```
Request.find()
    .populate({
        path: 'user',
        populate: {
            path: 'manager'
            match: { 'email' : 'johnDoe@acme.com'
        }
    }).exec(etc...)
```

but this returns all requests, but only populates 'manager' when that manager happens to be john doe.

Can any one guide me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.